Are all packages necessarily reproducible on GUIX?
By default, what will happen if I try to install a package with GUIX and it's not bit-for-bit reproducible?
I'm very concerned about the state of package managers in 2024 (and the risks of supply chain attacks). While traditional package managers like apt and yum are maintained by a dedicated team of package managers who verify, test, and cryptographially sign all their releases, new package managers like flatpak, snap, and docker allow random users to submit packages, and will happily download and run maliciously-modified software.
Today I learned about GUIX, which emphasizes reproducible builds. But after spending an hour reading their docs, I could not determine how reproducible builds in GUIX works -- nor if it's enforced for all packages.
Does a default install of GUIX require builds to be reproducible? How does it ensure authenticity of the software and resulting binary? What are the possible vulnerabilities to this system?


By default, what will happen if I try to install a package with GUIX and it's not bit-for-bit reproducible?

Nothing special, the package gets installed.
But if you actually try and reproduce the package, and the GUIX source package turns out to produce something different than what is in the corresponding GUIX binary package, then you'll get to sound the alarm.
The GUIX package manager makes this easy by providing a unique feature to automate this: the guix challenge command.
However, building everything from source to verify their reproducibility is extremely tedious, and if you run a fleet of 20 systems, you probably wouldn't want to build each package 20 times: instead, you might set each system to run the challenge on a different set of packages, to parallelize the verification.
Or if you aren't quite so hardcore as to challenge every package, you might find some reliable GUIX users and mostly trust their word when they say they've already challenged a particular package and found them reproducible. Maybe you would still randomly challenge some packages every now and then, to keep honest people honest. If enough people do this, any non-reproducibility gets caught quickly, while the workload gets shared.
In other words, it falls to you to decide which packets to challenge, and how often, based on your available computing resources and desired vigilance level.
Also, remember that reproducibility alone does not guarantee the absence of malicious code: if nobody reads the actual source code, an evil person might manage to inject evil code into the GUIX source repositories and get perfectly reproducible evil binary packages as a result.

"you might find some reliable GUIX users and mostly trust their word when they say they've already challenged a particular package" Is that an actual process? Like when I run guix challenge, does GUIX have my machine publish a cryptographically singed attestation that the package was verified by me? How do I browse this list of attestations  by others confirming the reproducibility of a given package in guix?

"In other words, it falls to you to decide which packets to challenge" How do I configure guix to always verify the reproducibility of a package before installing it? Is that an option that I can set somewhere in the guix config?

"If you run a fleet of 20 systems, you probably wouldn't want to build each package 20 times" Is this an existing concept or would I have to design it myself? I think it would be reasonable to run my own on-site guix mirror where every time a new package/version is installed by one machine in my fleet, it requires the package to be reproducible. And once that's done once, future installs from my guix mirror would skip the challenge. Does guix have any configuration options for setting this up or would I have to write it from scratch?

I think you'd have to write that from scratch
